# Jmeter , I'm facing 403 error when i try to run a login test

Tags: jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJS7s.png)

I used the Regular Expression Extractor for the tokens, but the 403 forbidden error keeps displaying.-check the screenshoot

Answer (score 0):

Seems some missing configuration issue.

Can you please make sure:

- You have HTTP Cookie Manager added to your Test Plan
- If your application is protected with external authentication system like Basic HTTP Authentication, NTLM or Kerberos you need to handle it properly using HTTP Authorization Manager

Can you try :

- Adding HTTP Header Manager and authorization with Basic encoded

Comment: I used the BlazeMeter to record the requests, all these already exist

Answer (score 0):

one screenshot of the failed response headers doesn't tell the full story, you need to show us:

1. Successful request URL, body (if any) and headers (you can get it from [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools))
2. Failing request from JMeter URL, body (if any) and headers from the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

As per [HTTP Status Code 403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) description:

> The HTTP **403 Forbidden** client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.
>
> This status is similar to [401](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401), but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.

If you can successfully execute the same scenario using browser and cannot using JMeter - most probably it's due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter), try recording the same steps one more time and compare generated scripts, all values which are different needs to be properly worked around